# Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I'm trying to create a violin plot on a rocky shore survey, exposed vs sheltered. I keep have groups deleted that I need.

```
# Violin plot

P5s <- ggplot(Example_data, aes(x=Species, y=Mean_perc), font="calibri")+
  geom_violin()
P5s

# Violin plot with difference between sheltered and exposed side

P6se <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Species, y=Mean_perc, fill=Location), font="calibri")+
  geom_violin()+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("Exposed","Sheltered"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust= 0.5))
P6se
```

I have my data set:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmcS5WkDAjIbhGHqGXCBziSnQ3Kh?e=TFR7ZA

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.  One can’t draw a violin with a single point.  What would you like to do instead?

Answer (score 0):

needed to add a mean dot to show up on the plot

Answer (score 0):

As @Dave2e points out, you can’t draw a density function with just one point. One option would be to plot a point for species where n == 1:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Example_data <- Example_data %>%
  add_count(Species, name = "Species_n") %>%
  add_count(Species, Location, name = "Species_loc_n")

# Violin plot

P5s <- ggplot(Example_data, aes(x=Species, y=Mean_perc))+
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(data = filter(Example_data, Species_n == 1))
P5s
```

[image]

```
# Violin plot with difference between sheltered and exposed side

P6se <- ggplot(Example_data, aes(x=Species, y=Mean_perc, fill=Location))+
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(
    data = filter(Example_data, Species_loc_n == 1), 
    aes(color = Location), 
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("Exposed","Sheltered"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust= 0.5))
P6se
```

[image]

Violins might not be the best choice for these data, though. I would try it with boxplots, or maybe just a simple scatterplot.